# New debug icon "Step F9" in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So what does this actualy do?

[image]

I searched trough the release notes of the Chrome Dev Tools and couldn't find a trace of it. None of the tutorials out there don't mention it either so I'm guessing it's new.

Experimenting with some code I seems to behave the same as "Step Into" and couldn't find a difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They have changed the existing "step into" button so it will now step into async functions (such as `setTimeout`).

So this new "Step F9" button works in the same way as the old "step into" button used to work, whereby it will step over the async function and onto the next line.

This page from google has a nice animated GIF which visually explains the above

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#async

Comment: Thanks @hman. That link also has a video where the change is explained.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake on the linked page: It's showing the **same** visualization for **Figure 10** and **Figure 11**