# What's the difference of Step and Step Into in Google Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, chromium, developer-tools

[image]

What is the difference of "Step" and "Step into" in Google Chrome Developer tools,?
I even can't find it in docs
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code

[image]

Comment: `step`: execute a line of code, `step into`: Same as `step` but if it's a function then it will go into that function and then pause the debugger at it's first line, which will allow you to debug the called functions too

Comment: @Asesh so step will step over that function? then what'll the step over do

Comment: Yes you are right. Step over will step out of function, incase you don't want to go through that function

Comment: @Asesh Hi, I still don't know the difference of 'step' and 'step into'  
```
function fun(a,b){
    console.log(23);
    console.log(15);
    console.log(1);console.log(2);
    return a+b
}


debugger

console.log(fun(1,2));

console.log(15);

console.log(r);
```
this looks work same, can you explain it again? thank you

Comment: My first comment already answers your questions. Also the link you have specified, answers your question too

Comment: @Asesh The images in the link even have no 'step' options, only 'step into' 'step over'  and 'step out' , and in my browser, I didn't find any difference. between 'step' and 'step into', maybe can you give me a example code, to distinguish them in this answer...

Comment: This is one of those things that you could have solved yourself by actually trying. Had you asked the difference between step over and step then a little more benefit of the doubt your way.

Comment: @user956609, no, step over does NOT step out of a function.  That is step out (default S-F11).

Comment: in the sample code you put in your comment, step and step into will do the same thing on every line, except the line that calls `fun(1,2)`. On that line, step into will step in to the function fun. (It won't step in to console.log because it is not one where you have access to the js)

Comment: For those coming here to figure out what the "Step" command does (as distinct from Step Over, Step In, and Step Out), see the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608073/new-debug-icon-step-f9-in-chrome-dev-tools - bu basically, it's like Step In, unless the function is async, then it's like Step Over.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can spot the difference while running async code or multi-threaded code.

**Step into**: DevTools assumes that you want to pause in the asynchronous code
that eventually runs

**Step**: DevTools pause in code as it chronologically ran

Consider this example:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('inside')
}, 3000);

console.log('outside')
```

After stopping on the breakpoint on the first line (`setTimeout(() => {`).

**Step into**: it waits 3 seconds and stops on the 2nd line (`console.log('inside')`)

**Step** it pauses on the 4th line (`console.log('outside')`)

Link to the docs:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#async