# What's the difference between Step, Step into, and Step over in in a debugger?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I think I have an idea of what the difference between Step Into and Step Over is.

The confusion comes when comparing Step and Step Into. I couldn't find anything online about difference between both.

Is it related to the way the debugger treats async code?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance No. That question is only related to Step Into and Step Over. It doesn't mention Step anywhere.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/q/64429688/4294399

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608073/new-debug-icon-step-f9-in-chrome-dev-tools is the dup which actually explains what the new "Step" does. Apparently it's like a midway between "step into" and "step over", in that it steps into functions, but over async functions like SetTimeout.